# How can I unzip a large file in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, zip, pyspark, unzip

I need to unzip a 1.6G file in PySpark.

I've tried doing things along the lines of:

```
unzipped_files = sc.union( \
                        [sc.binaryFiles(path) for path in paths]) \
                           .flatMap(lambda kv: unzip_file(kv) \
                         )
```

where `paths` is a list of filepaths (that currently just has one element) and `unzip_file` looks something along the lines of:

```
zipped_file_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(zipped_file[1]), "r")

return [
        zipped_file_obj.open(filename).read() 
        for filename in zipped_file_obj.namelist()
       ]
```

but the resulting `unzipped_files` RDD I get is completely unusable. Things as simple as `.isEmpty()` cause the job to get shut down with a message like `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.` which doesn't help me AT ALL.

Even if I try to just do the following:

```
file = sc.binaryFiles(paths[0])
```

*that* is a completely unusable RDD, as well. I'm about to pull my hair out here. Is the file just too big?